# Python- How to update column by taking substring from another column?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, python-3.5

I have a list which looks like this: `li = ['ShortHair','LongHair','Medium Hair']`

I want to check if col2 contains any of the above substring, if it does take it from col2 and update col3. If it doesnot, then leave col3 as it is.

```
     col1   col2               col3
0       w   I have ShortHair      U
1       x   LongHair You Have     V
2       y   I have no hair        W
3       z   Look Medium Hair!     L
```

to get:

```
     col1   col2               col3
0       w   I have             ShortHair
1       x   You Have           LongHair
2       y   I have no hair        W
3       z   Look !             Medium Hair
```

**EDIT:** If multiple occurences of substring are there in the array, remove both form col2 and update col3 with first value.

I am able to remove substring from col2, however I am not able to update col3. I tried:

```
data[data.col2.str.contains('|'.join(li)),"col3"] = data["col2"].map(lambda x: re.findall('|'.join(li),x)[0])
```

It gives `IndexError: list index out of range` error.

How can I best do this?

Comment: What if "You Have LongHair or ShortHair"? What should col3 contain and why?

Comment: Remove both, keep first. I will update the question

Comment: @Alexander I am sure that this won't happen in the dataset that I am using. However, for my purposes, taking first value should suffice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create sample dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'col1': ['w', 'x', 'y', 'z'],
     'col2': ['I have ShortHair', 'LongHair You Have', 'I have no hair', 'Look Medium Hair!'],
     'col3': ['U', 'V', 'W', 'L']})
```

Use a lambda expression with a list comprehension to find all matching words on each row.  This is a temporary column that will be deleted later.

```
df['matches'] = df.col2.apply(lambda sentence: [word for word in li if word in sentence])
```

Create a mask of those rows containing matching words.

```
mask = df.matches.apply(len) > 0
```

Using the mask and `.loc`, update `col3` with the first matching word.

```
df.loc[mask, 'col3'] = df.loc[mask, 'matches'].str[0]
```

Use a lambda expression together with `reduce` to remove each matching word from `col2`:

```
df.loc[mask, 'col2'] = (
    df.loc[mask, 'col2'].apply(lambda sentence: 
                               reduce(lambda remaining_sentence, word: 
                                      remaining_sentence.replace(word, ''), li, sentence)))
```

Delete the temporary column of matched words.

```
del df['matches']
```

Confirm the results.

```
>>> df
  col1            col2         col3
0    w         I have     ShortHair
1    x        You Have     LongHair
2    y  I have no hair            W
3    z          Look !  Medium Hair
```